# What does it mean when c++ template definition comes with =

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm trying to teach myself generic classes and functions declaration and Boost library at the sometime.
I've encountered an example and don't really understand what `typename f=...` means.
Could you help me to understand the concept of using template declaration  with `=` sign in cases like: `template <typename T, typename F=ublas::row_major>`? Here is the full program that I'm trying to understand.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;

template <typename T, typename F=ublas::row_major>
ublas::matrix<T, F> makeMatrix(std::size_t m, std::size_t n, const std::vector<T> & v)
{
    if(m*n!=v.size()) {
        ; // Handle this case
    }
    ublas::unbounded_array<T> storage(m*n);
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), storage.begin());
    return ublas::matrix<T>(m, n, storage);
}
```

Comment: `F=ublas::row_major` default template argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a default value/type for the entry parameter of that template-d function. It's like compiler write down `ublas::row_major` everywhere you've written `F`, when you call `makeMatrix` without second template argument.

```
makeMatrix<int, int>( ...      // Second parameter is `int`

makeMatrix<int> ( ...   // Second is specified by default to `ublas::row_major`
```

[To read more..](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

Answer (score 3):

It is Default Argument that you are passing to Template.
e.g

```
 Template<typename T, int N = 17>
  class Generic
  {



   }
```

here, second Argument is default value

in youe case **F=ublas::row_major** is default value.

for deep understanding http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Answer (score 2):

It is a default argument, which is used when nothing else is specified.